# ERROR:: Unknown Directory structure, both java & kotlin files not found

Tags: flutter, dart, package, dart-pub

As I was trying to change my package name using a package ([change_app_package_name](https://pub.dev/packages/change_app_package_name)). I bumped into this error:-

```
Old Package Name: com.milanzi.shamba_huru
Updating build.gradle File
Updating Main Manifest file
Updating Debug Manifest file
Updating Profile Manifest file

ERROR:: Unknown Directory structure, both java & kotlin files not found.
```

Seems the package cannot find either java or kotlin files within the directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved by changing the directory name where the `MainActivity.kt` is placed

**For example**

- First your package name is `com.example.app_name`
- Then you need to change into `com.milanzi.shamba_huru` (use your own package name)
- Run

  flutter pub run change_app_package_name:main com.milanzi.shamba_huru

So if the error appears, you just need to create a new folder by name of your package

- Before your path was
  `/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/example/app_name/MainActivity.kt`
- Change into
  `/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/milanzi/shamba_huru/MainActivity.kt`
- Now try run against `flutter pub run change_app_package_name:main com.milanzi.shamba_huru`

**NB:** If you didn't change the folder name, you can't run it on android. But you can run on IOS.